# To call js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript i dont know how to call the javascript file from any html.Pls help me.

```
<div class="subject"></div>
<script>

    $("#course_code_id").live("change keypress",function(){
    var id = 0;
    id = $(this).val();
    if( $(this).val() !==''){           
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('subject/search_by_course') ?>',
            {
                subject_id: id
            },function(data){
                $(".subject").html( data['html_string']);

            },"JSON"
        );

   }
});</script
```

>

Comment: Call what? it will be executed once the HTML is loaded. BTW, `live` is dead, since version 1.9 it's removed from jQuery source code.

Comment: I really have no idea what question you're asking here.

Comment: if i have a html tag how i can call a js file @Mike W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you wrote will be executed when  the page loads. But to ensure that it start to be executed only after jQuery is loaded, you should do this:

```
<div class="subject"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#course_code_id").live("change keypress",function(){
       var id = 0;
       id = $(this).val();
       if( $(this).val() !==''){           
          $.post('<?php echo site_url('subject/search_by_course') ?>',
            {
                subject_id: id
            },function(data){
                $(".subject").html( data['html_string']);

            },"JSON"
          );
       }
   });
});
</script>
```